How Do You Check People In For Events?
Every solution we have tried to implement to check people in for events has been a pain. I run a small and big non-profit website. The former for free.
An ideal check in  experience would include:

QR code emailed as part of registration, when they arrive staff check them in by scanning QR code with a device logged into CiviCRM site. When we check them in, we can see their role, status, ticket level, etc. If they bought more than one ticket, ability to check in 1 ticket at a time.
User lost email, no big deal, can easily switch browser tabs and review their ticket information and check them in. If they bought multiple tickets, can check in all or one at a time.

These are things we have tried so far.
Using Participant Search to check people in on a laptop is too time consuming when you have 100 people waiting in line.
QR Code Check In doesn't work for us because it doesn't send the QR Code with the registration. People can register for our events during the event which makes it difficult and it requires us to send a separate email with qr code after they register. Its an incomplete solution but could be a good solution.
CiviMobile just doesnt work on our sites. It used to be an okay but limited solution, but now doesnt work. Limited in the sense that you just tap on peoples names to check them in, you don't see what ticket they  bought, etc.
CiviMobile API works great but might be requiring too many resources on our site, because it crashes. Not sure why - we might invest to figure out more. But also seems to interfere with OSSSeed Calendar. Would also be nice to be able to use on desktop/laptop.

Here's another alternative for generating qr codes that point to a registration link:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin
Documented here:
https://network.progressivetech.org/node/1308
Technically, a qr code is just a url written in a fun way, so generating a qr code for a registration link is a relatively straightforward task that doesn't need to be bundled with lots of other stuff.

I included this one in my post. Its okay, we have used it before, but it does not send QR codes to attendees when they register - we have to manually email users a QR code, which to the user is confusing.

Okay, I wasn't paying attention! Also, I'm still learning ... but, does it offer a token? That would seem like the easy way to include a QR code in your registration thingy.

no worries and thank you. It does provide a QR code token for email communications, a separate token is created per event. I've tried including the token in the event registration email, but it does not work. Only in emails created in civimail or email send now.

maybe have a look at our Event-Checkin Extension (de.systopia.eventcheckin). I have not grasped your use case completely but it should provide all the features required. You can also combine it with the Event Communication Extension and the Remote Event Extension for even more automated workflows.

Thanks, ill give these a try - i remember installing them a long time ago and having a lot of trouble (site crashed upon install/uninstall), but I see a lot of changes since then. Will try again, thanks again!

Please do - we are not aware of any critical issues and our customers are using it regularly. I have written up a comprehensive guide for a setup - it is in German but I am sure any tranbslation tool will do the trick: https://community.software-fuer-engagierte.de/t/fancy-events-mit-civicrm/250

I've been using the QR Code Checkin extension. While it does not send a QR code at event registration, I always send out event reminders and whatnot to include the QR code. Understood this doesn't quite work in your situation as you have people registering at the end -- wondering if some kind of trigger could be added for event registration to send an email automatically?
Ran into a problem with it the last time we had an event that used it a couple weeks ago, where the checkin process just said "sorry, an error occurred." This was due to needing to run "civix upgrade" on the extension after the Smarty upgrade.
